# How to cope with IDENTITY_INSERT for an INSTEAD OF trigger on a table with an IDENTITY column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, insert, identity

I have a table with an `IDENTITY` column, and I have an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on this table.  If `IDENTITY_INSERT` got turned on, I would want to insert the value being manually specified for the `IDENTITY` column.

Is there any way to properly cope with this scenario, such as detecting the value of `IDENTITY_INSERT`?  From reading, it looks like detecting the current value of `IDENTITY_INSERT` for a specific table has been impossible in the past.  I don't know if it's possible with newer versions of SQL Server.

Table creation SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [TestTable]
(
    [Id]            INTEGER IDENTITY    NOT NULL    PRIMARY KEY,
    [ExampleField]  BIT                 NOT NULL    DEFAULT(1)
)
```

This is what I've currently tried, but it seems rather wasteful as `IDENTITY_INSERT` is likely to be off for most of the time, meaning that it's always going to be failing on the first insert attempt, which seems wasteful, performance-wise.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trTestTable_ioi] ON [dbo].[TestTable] INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO [TestTable]([Id],[ExampleField])
        SELECT [Id], [ExampleField]
        FROM [inserted]
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        INSERT INTO [TestTable]([ExampleField])
        SELECT [ExampleField]
        FROM [inserted]
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: If you think need to use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` you should probably not use Identity in the first place. Moreover, if you have an instead of insert on a table, combining that with an Identity column might prove to be a paint in the neck.

Answer (score 1):

If your `IDENTITY` seed and increment is such that the generated value will always be non-zero (positive seed and increment or negative seed and increment), you can check for non-zero values in the virtual `inserted` table and use that value when present. This relies on my observation that the identity value is zero with an `INSTEAD OF` trigger and `IDENTITY_INSERT OFF`. However, I could not find this behavior specifically documented so you should vet in your environment and use at your own risk.

Example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trTestTable_ioi] ON [dbo].[TestTable] INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE ID <> 0)
BEGIN
    --IDENTITY_INSERT is ON
    INSERT INTO [TestTable]([Id],[ExampleField])
    SELECT [Id], [ExampleField]
    FROM [inserted];
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    --IDENTITY_INSERT is OFF
    INSERT INTO [TestTable]([ExampleField])
    SELECT [ExampleField]
    FROM [inserted];
END;
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.TestTable OFF;
GO
--identity value auto-assigned
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES(1);
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.TestTable ON;
GO
--explict identity value specified
INSERT INTO TestTable(ID, ExampleField) VALUES(11, 1);
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.TestTable OFF;
GO
--fails as expected because identity value cannot be specified with IDENTITY_INSERT OFF
INSERT INTO TestTable(ID, ExampleField) VALUES(11, 1);
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.TestTable ON;
GO
--fails as expected because identity value must be specified with IDENTITY_INSERT ON
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES(1);
GO
```

Comment: Interesting observation! It looks like the trigger does not actually execute at all if `IDENTITY_INSERT` is `OFF` and you try and insert into an `IDENTITY` column. I could therefore probably trust that if my `IDENTITY` column is a non-zero value in the `[inserted]` table then `IDENTITY_INSERT` must be off. As you say though, some documentation on this functionality would certainly be handy. My best guess would be that it's a performance-saving check that is performed before the `INSERT` operation is even attempted (because such an `INSERT` will always fail without `SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF`).

Comment: @Interminable, SQL Server won't even attempt to execute an `INSERT` when the statement violates IDENTITY_INSERT rules so neither the outer insert nor the trigger executes. This is the same behavior with or without the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for `set identity_insert` states:

> At any time, only one table in a session can have the IDENTITY_INSERT
>   property set to ON. If a table already has this property set to ON,
>   and a SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON statement is issued for another table,
>   SQL Server returns an error message that states SET IDENTITY_INSERT is
>   already ON and reports the table it is set ON for.

A *terrible* idea is to create a temporary table and try setting `identity_insert on` for it. If there is an error, catch the message and extract the table name.

**NB:** Any time you are catching and parsing an error message you are fiddling with some fragile code. You should run, not walk, away *now*.

```
create table #Placeholder ( Id Int Identity );
begin try
  set identity_insert #Placeholder on;
end try
begin catch
  -- Sample error: IDENTITY_INSERT is already ON for table 'Scratch.dbo.Foo'. Cannot perform SET operation for table '#Placeholder'.
  declare @Message as NVarChar(2048) = Error_Message();
  print @Message;
  declare @Prefix as NVarChar(2048) = 'IDENTITY_INSERT is already ON for table ''';
  declare @Suffix as NVarChar(2048) = '''. Cannot perform SET operation for table ''#Placeholder''.';
  declare @TableName as NVarChar(2048) = NULL;
  if ( Left( @Message, Len( @Prefix ) ) = @Prefix and Right( @Message, Len( @Suffix ) ) = @Suffix )
    set @TableName = Substring( @Message, Len( @Prefix ) + 1, Len( @Message ) - Len( @Prefix ) - Len( @Suffix ) );
  else
    print 'Unexpected error!';
  print @TableName;    
end catch
drop table #Placeholder;
```

Then there are the performance implications of creating/dropping a temporary table in a trigger.

Comment: What you wrote is correct, however it doesn't fit the question I guess either the question was edited during the grace period after your answer was already posted or you mistakenly answered the wrong question. Either way, while the content is good, I fail to see how it relates to the question so I will not upvote it.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Whilst I *think* I may have edited the question very soon after posting it (it was very late last night), this answer was posted 4 hours afterwards.  It does seem to be a reasonable attempt to answer it and has given me an idea towards this.

@HABO You're right that string checking is fragile, but why does that need to be done? Surely I can just check if `ERROR_NUMBER()` is `8107`, as googling suggests that's the specific error number for this, although I did not know about this error before!  Also, the temp table could be created with `TINYINT` as it will never hold any records.

Comment: I'm also not sure if creating the temporary table with `TINYINT` will improve the performance of creating a temporary table in a trigger.

Comment: This approach also appears to have serious issues with transactions, as it appears to doom them despite the `CATCH`.

Comment: @Interminable I considered checking `Error_Number()`, but the only way to obtain the _name_ of the table with `identity_insert` turned on is by extracting it from `Error_Message()`. It may be the table of interest to the trigger or it could be another table.

Comment: @HABO Ah, I see.  If the whole thing didn't damage the transaction state, what you could try is once the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT #Placeholder ON` attempt fails, you could then try it on the table you're actually trying to insert into.  If *that* succeeds, you would know that `IDENTITY_INSERT` is on for the table you're trying to insert into, and not another.  It does mean you'd need to catch the error twice, but it could probably be considered more robust than trying to parse the error string.